# Book about the UN taking over the world

Tags: story-identification, books

A few years ago, I remember reading a reference about a fictional book in which the UN Secretary General launches an ambitious and well-meaning worldwide campaign to reduce arms trafficking. The plan is so successful, that member countries begin to give the office of the Secretary General more and more political powers. Eventually the UN becomes so powerful that it starts taking over countries and eventually becomes Earth's overall governing body and starts a planet-wide oppressive regime. Is not A Brave New World btw. For some reason I can't find it, and I know I didn't just imagined this.

Comment: It must be fiction. In reality the UN can barely take over the UN building

Comment: lol, yeah. I'm a huge believer in the eventually of a unified world government, and this premise sounds so interesting to me.

Comment: lol. Never gonna happen. Maybe at the point of a gun

Comment: @fer04i Then you might like the Expanse, as the UN is the official government of Earth.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, when you say "a fictional book" do you mean a real book in the science fiction genre, or are you looking for, e.g., a science fiction story in which someone reads the book you describe?  (Your question reminds me of [Shah Guido G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shah_Guido_G.) but that's a short story and doesn't go into the level of detail you describe.)

Comment: A book about a fictional reality in which the UN takes over the world.

Comment: The Expanse, that's a TV show isn't it? I'll check it out. The HALO version of the UN is definitely my favorite one.

Comment: An oppressive UN regime is a key aspect of the novel [Emerald Eyes](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1262998).